# add margin-top and bottom on a div in a table with mpdf

Tags: css, mpdf

I am facing a problem when i try to add the *margin-top* or *margin-bottom* on div elements inside a table for generating pdf with **mpdf**.

I have something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div style="margin-top: 20px;">Element1</div>
        <div style="margin-top: 20px;">Element2</div>
        ...
    </td>

    <td>
        <div style="margin-top: 20px;">Element4</div>
        <div style="margin-top: 20px;">Element5</div>
        ...
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**The margin styles are not converted.**

I think it could be because there are too many nested elements and mpdf doesnt support them in some cases. Have someone already achieved such a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i have found another way to achieve this without using **margin** style.
 I have just used the simple tag `<br>` to create space between my elements.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <br><br>
    <div>Element1</div>
    <br><br>
    <div>Element2</div>
    ...
</td>

<td>
    <br><br>
    <div>Element4</div>
    <br><br>
    <div>Element5</div>
    ...
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Mpdf** has some limitations in CSS. Sometimes to achieve some tasks we have to think another way. **Thanks**.